# How do I make my enemySprite respawn as new bad guy once its been killed?

Tags: ios, swift, collision

I am having trouble with my game, I've managed to have my enemySprites all shoot at the hero in a synchronized matter and I've gotten them to play the "killed" animation once they've been hit. Although I've run into a rather small matter which I was really hoping you guys could help me with. The problem I have is that when my badGuy is killed they move off the screen and I don't know how I can program it so that a 'new' badGuy appears forever until the Hero sprite is killed.

This is my function to spawn my enemy:

```
func spawnEnemy(targetSprite: SKNode) -> SKSpriteNode {
    if !gamePaused{
    // create a new enemy sprite
    let main = GameScene()
    newEnemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"BNG1_1.png")
    enemySprite.append(newEnemy)//ADD TO THE LIBRARY OF BADGUYS
    newEnemy.xScale = 1.2
    newEnemy.yScale = 0.6
        newEnemy.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        newEnemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: newEnemy.texture, size: newEnemy.size)
        newEnemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        newEnemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.badguyCollision.rawValue
        newEnemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.beamCollison.rawValue
        newEnemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0
    let muv : UInt32 = (200 + (arc4random()%500))

    let actualDuration = NSTimeInterval(random(min: CGFloat(3.0), max: CGFloat(4.0)))
    let randomNum = CGPoint(x:Int (muv), y:Int (arc4random()%500))
    // Create the actions
    var actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(randomNum, duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration))
    newEnemy.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove]))

    // position new sprite at a random position on the screen
    var posX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(sizeRect.size.width))
    var posY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(sizeRect.size.height))
    newEnemy.position = CGPoint(x: screenSize.width*2 + newEnemy.size.width, y: random(min: newEnemy.size.height, max: screenSize.height - newEnemy.size.height))


    let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "BG1.atlas")

    let anime = SKAction.animateWithTextures([atlas.textureNamed("BG1_1.png"), atlas.textureNamed("BG1_2.png"),
        atlas.textureNamed("BG1_3.png"),
        atlas.textureNamed("BG1_2.png"),
        atlas.textureNamed("BG1_1.png")], timePerFrame: 0.1)
    dinoRun = SKAction.repeatActionForever(anime)
    newEnemy.runAction(dinoRun)

    }
    return newEnemy
}
```

And this is my function for once they are hit (this function is called when the collisionTest between my hero's laser and the badguy is recognized):

```
func deadBadGuy(){
    //animation
    var dinoRun:SKAction
    var newdes = CGPoint(x: Int(arc4random()%500), y:0)
    var actionMoov = SKAction.moveTo(newdes, duration: 3)
    var goaway = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let aTlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "dedBG.atlas")
    let anime = SKAction.animateWithTextures([aTlas.textureNamed("deadBG1.png"), aTlas.textureNamed("deadBG2.png"),
        aTlas.textureNamed("deadBG3.png"),
        aTlas.textureNamed("deadBG2.png"),
        aTlas.textureNamed("deadBG1.png")], timePerFrame: 0.1)
    dinoRun = SKAction.repeatActionForever(anime)
    newEnemy.runAction(dinoRun)
    newEnemy.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMoov,goaway]))
    score++
    self.scoreNode.text = String(score)
    enemySprites.newPlace(neewEnemy)
    dead = true //i created this Boolean because the sprite keeps shooting even if its dead
}
```

This is the way I called for the collisionTest in my program in case you need it for more information:

```
func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact){
    if !gamePaused {
        let firstNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
        switch(firstNode){
        case BodyType.beamCollison.rawValue | BodyType.badguyCollision.rawValue:
            deadBadGuy()
            //enemySprites.spawnEnemy(sprite)
        default:
            print("hit")

        }
```

Note: I tried having the func spawnEnemy being called during the collisionTest but that results in the BadGuy staying off screen shooting at my hero.

**Update :** I found out how to add a new enemy sprite once the other is dead all i had to do was

```
newEnemy.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMoov,goaway]), completion: {
       self.addChild(self.enemySprites.spawnEnemy(sprite))
        })
```

in the deadBadGuy function(the spawnEnemy function is in another class which I named enemySprites as a variable). However now I've run into a new issue and that is that it adds 10 enemySprites instead of one. How can I change that?

**Update 2 :** I figured out that issue too, I just needed to remove to dead Boolean method in the deadBadGuy function.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer and all I had to do was add this line to my deadBadGuy function and remove the dead boolean methods

```
newEnemy.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMoov,goaway]), completion: {
   self.addChild(self.enemySprites.spawnEnemy(sprite))
    })
```